# Python syntax error when trying to access path parameter in chalice

Tags: python, chalice

I am trying to access a path parameter using chalice but it's giving me a syntax error.

py file

```
@app.route('/someValue/{indicator}', methods=['GET']
def get_indicator_value(indicator):
```

Gives me this error mentioned below:

```
[ERROR] Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: Syntax error in module 'test': invalid syntax (test.py, line 74)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/test.py" Line 74
    def some_value(indicator):
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: You are missing the closing `)` on the call to `app.route`.

Comment: Sorry. That was very silly of me .

Answer (score 1):

In the first line, you are missing the `)` at the end. This is the fixed code:

```
@app.route('/someValue/{indicator}', methods=['GET'])
def get_indicator_value(indicator):
```